# Android 6.0 Bluetooth Program Cannot Discover Any Available Bluetooth Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

**GOAL**

Discovering all the available bluetooth devices such as my iPad with bluetooth ON (Discoverable).

**ANDROID VERSION**

6.0

**PROBLEM**

Cannot Discover any bluetooth devices.

**CODE**

```
// Permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
public IntentFilter filter;

private boolean discover_AvailableBluetoothDevice() {
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive Called");
                String action = intent.getAction();
                // When discovery finds a device
                if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED");
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED");
                } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_FOUND");
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                    String str = device.getName() + "\n( " + device.getAddress() + " )";
                    adapter.add(str);
                }
            }
        };

        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        boolean isSuccessDiscovery = mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        return isSuccessDiscovery;
    }
```

**EXECUTION RESULT (logcat)**

```
02-02 01:17:26.142 7194-7194/eie.imt.smartswitch D/†MainActivity: This device support Bluetooth.
02-02 01:17:55.052 7194-7194/eie.imt.smartswitch D/†ConnectSwitchActivity: isSuccessDiscovery=true
02-02 01:17:55.147 7194-7194/eie.imt.smartswitch D/†ConnectSwitchActivity: onReceive Called
02-02 01:17:55.147 7194-7194/eie.imt.smartswitch D/†ConnectSwitchActivity: ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED
02-02 01:18:07.909 7194-7194/eie.imt.smartswitch D/†ConnectSwitchActivity: onReceive Called
02-02 01:18:07.910 7194-7194/eie.imt.smartswitch D/†ConnectSwitchActivity: ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
```

I see the program does not enter the condition block of **ACTION_FOUND** but my iPad's bluetooth is ON, where does the problem come from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use Android 6, add one of the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCTION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

And turn on the Location service (GPS):

[image]

And turn on the Location permission:

[image]

Google now requires `ACCESS_FINE_LOCTION` or `ACCESS_COARCE_LOCATION` permissions to be able to scan for Bluetooth or Wifi devices. It's weird behavior but Google says it's how it should work from now on.

[Link to AndroidDev about this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)

Comment: I already added those two permissions you memtioned but the result seems the same.

Comment: Make sure you enabled gps and all permissions for app through settings

Comment: Not sure if helpful but I've come across a similar issue in Android 7.0 and I did need to enable the Location permission for my app, but did not need to actually turn Location on.